# Как с помощью стилей сделать круг с ядром внутри и орбитой снаружи?

Tags: html, css, css3, изображения

Есть `input[type="range"]`. Подскажите, как сделать ползунок такой, как на картинке с ядром внутри и орбитой снаружи (серый фон не в счет) желательно с помощью `css`? 
К сожалению, псевдоклассы здесь не применимы..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: green;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.4);
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range" min="100" max="1000" step="50" value="650">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ обычный, с использованием фонового изображения. Если необходимо то изображение можно преобразовать в base64 и вставить внутрь кода.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r69Sx.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

Способ еще проще, подбираем размеры толщины рамки, и добавляем тень для контейнера:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid white 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px silver;
}
```

Comment: ну, если нет способа получше, типа векторной картинки или стиля, то ок, спасибо

Comment: векторную картинку можно подгрузить так же как и обычную, нужно применить ее к `background-image: url("icon.svg");` Поддержка движками в норме [https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css]

Comment: а откуда ее взять эту векторную картинку?

Comment: либо создать в онлайн-редакторе новую в svg формате, либо же, конвертировать из существующей png картинки в svg

Comment: к сожалению, не знаю, как в онайн-редакторе рисовать svg-объекты. я имел ввиду что-то типа того https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajrpQG но да конца правильно довести не получается..

Comment: Такой вариант, можно реализовать с использованием небольшого скрипта, то есть реализовать аналог такого компонента(input[type=range]), вот мой пример, там можно масштабировать векторную окружность (https://codepen.io/Fedak/pen/PdYYMJ)